# New line or return being added to text file with out prompt

Tags: php

first off I'm a noob to PHP but here is my problem. I am trying to read a line from a text file, manipulate the line then write the original and new line to a new text file. For some reason it adds an extra return or new line in the output file.

**Original File Text**

```
/Volumes/EC/EC_0101/B-W Art/001_0101.EPS
...
/Volumes/EC/EC_0101/B-W Art/010_0101.EPS
```

**HTML Output for Testing**

```
EC:EC_0101:B-W Art:001_0101.EPS EC EC_0101 B-W Art 001_0101.EPS
...
EC:EC_0101:B-W Art:010_0101.EPS EC EC_0101 B-W Art 010_0101.EPS
```

**New Text File Output**

```
EC:EC_0101:B-W Art:001_0101.EPS
    EC  EC_0101 B-W Art 001_0101.EPS
...
EC:EC_0101:B-W Art:010_0101.EPS
    EC  EC_0101 B-W Art 010_0101.EPS
```

**Should be tab delimited**

```
EC:EC_0101:B-W Art:001_0101.EPS EC  EC_0101 B-W Art 001_0101.EPS
...
EC:EC_0101:B-W Art:010_0101.EPS EC  EC_0101 B-W Art 010_0101.EPS
```

**My Code**

```
$file = fopen("files_list.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$filename = "files_list_tab.txt";
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
  {
  $strLink = fgets($file);
  //$strComment = $strLink;

  $strLink= str_replace("/",":",$strLink);
  $strLink= str_replace(":Volumes:","",$strLink);
  $strComment= str_replace(":","\t",$strLink);

  $strCombined = $strLink."\t".$strComment;
  $array[] = $strCombined;

  echo $strCombined. "<br>";

  }
fclose($file);

echo "Done <br>";

$strCombined = $array;
file_put_contents($filename, $strCombined);
echo "Done <br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
...     
$strCombined = trim($strLink)."\t".$strComment;
...
```

Comment: Thank you, simple and straight forward answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah, it's in the original file.

Assume this:

```
// fgets() returns this
strLink = "/Volumes/EC/EC_0101/B-W Art/001_0101.EPS\n"

// then it becomes this
strLink = "EC:EC_0101:B-W Art:001_0101.EPS\n"
strComment = "EC\tEC_0101\tB-W Art\t001_0101.EPS\n"

// later you do this
strCombined = strLink + "\t" + strComment
```

Since both strLink and strComment ended with the original `\n`, it's there in `strCombined` as well.

Answer (score 0):

[`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) documentation reads:

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, on a newline (which
>   is included in the return value), or on EOF (whichever comes first).
>   If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until
>   it reaches the end of the line.

You could use `$strLink = trim(fgets($file));` to remove the line breaks before your processing.